# Port is forwarded correctly but can't access Tomcat outside LAN

Tags: java, tomcat

I have an issue with my Tomcat.

**What I want to do:**

I want to be able to access my webapp OUTSIDE my LAN. I'm using Tomcat as webserver, listening to port 9191.

The machine that is hosting Tomcat has STATIC IP (e.g 192.168.1.100). My network configuration is as following:

INTERNET ----- MY ROUTER ----- COMPUTER 1 
                         ----- COMPUTER 2 (STATIC IP: 192.168.1.XXX) - HOSTING TOMCAT

I've already tested the port forwarding with the PFPortChecker tool and it says that everything is working fine and the port is forwarded correctly.

**The problem:**

When I try **http:// localhost:9191/myAppName** or **http:// 192.168.1.XXX/myAppName**, it works, even if I try from another computer in the SAME LAN. . However, if I try **http:// mypublicip:9191/myAppName**. The browser says that it can't open the website. I'm desperate about this. I don't know what could I do anymore.

Tomcat Configuration:

server.xml: http://pastebin.com/vhnuEHBM

So, what could I do?

Comment: Di you sort of this issue? Please tell me what is a solution ?\

Comment: No, I haven't solved it yet. Unfortunately, it seems that computers outside the LAN can access the URL. But computers inside the LAN can't access it at all. I don't know why.

Comment: I don't think this is a problem with your setup, most likely a firewall issue or a router issue. Have you tried direct connect to your modem instead of going through the router?

Answer (score 0):

You have tomcat bound to the loopback interface. Either set it to 0.0.0.0 (to listen on all interfaces) or the static ip you've assigned to your computer.

Comment: It still doesn't work. If I set the configuration as you advised (check here, http://pastebin.com/tx5UNzaz) the behaviour is the same.

Comment: But as you can see (netstat screenshot: http://www28.zippyshare.com/v/57309182/file.html), it is listening to 0.0.0.0, on port 9191.

Comment: Then it is something in your port forwarding config.